# TPA3220: Single supply operation - can I use AVDD to pull up RESET?

Tags: amplifier

I've tried asking this question on the TI forums but have not been able to get a response, so I'm posting here in the hope that someone who knows the details of the TPA3220 will be able to answer!

I am designing a product that uses the [TPA3220](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3220.pdf#page=25) power amplifier in single supply mode (powered by a TPS55340 30V boost converter).

When in single supply mode, 5V is made available on the AVDD pin via an internal LDO (which is powered by the 30V single supply).

The amp is turned on by pulling the RESET pin to 5V. I'm wondering if RESET can be connected to the AVDD pin to turn on the amplifier?

On page 25 of the datasheet it says that "When RESET is released to turn on TPA3220, FAULT signal will turn low and AVDD voltage regulator will be enabled". This suggests that AVDD will not be available until RESET is already high, i.e connecting them would not work because it would create a circular dependency.

If this is the case, how should I turn on the amplifier if I am running it in single supply mode without an external 5V supply?

Comment: I haven't read the datasheet...  But off the top of my head you could use a resistor/zener to create a 5V level to release the (active low) reset line.  Alternately the term "is released" would indicate that it could simply float to turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use AVDD to create \$\overline{RESET}\$, since (circular dependency as OP states):

> When RESET is released to turn on TPA3220, FAULT signal will turn low and AVDD voltage regulator will be enabled

From the bottom of page 24 of the [TPA3220 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3220.pdf#page=24):

> The TPA3220 does not require a power-up sequence because of the integrated undervoltage protection (UVP), but it is **recommended** to hold \$\overline{RESET}\$ low until PVDD supply voltage is stable to avoid audio artifacts.

Recommended is not required.

First place to go is evaluation boards.

On the initial [evaluation board](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau754/slau754.pdf#page=14), TI did this via [TPS3802 voltage supervisor](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps3801.pdf).  \$\overline{RESET}\$ is held low until PVDD is stabilized.

[image: Reset Control]

On [Rev A of the evaluation board](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau756a/slau756a.pdf#page=16), they simplified it to:

[image: Reset Pullup]

They just used a pull-up resistor to the onboard 5V regulator.

**Answer:** You cannot use AVDD (OP circular dependency), but if you can live with possible audio artifacts on power up, use a voltage divider to give you 5V from the 30V boost converter for \$\overline{RESET}\$.  Otherwise, use a voltage supervisor.

I'd add both and populate as required.

Answer (score 1):

From this [document](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau756a/slau756a.pdf):

> Special consideration must be taken for the RESET pin. **The RESET pin
>   needs to have a 5-V input**. In order to do this R40 must be installed
>   to create a voltage divider network that will drop the voltage down to
>   5 V

It is certain that the RESET should be controlled.

[image]

The R40 (greyed out in the image) should be sized so that, the RESET pin will see 5 V when the need is there to deassert. If there is no stable power supply available (to work with voltage divider, as @SpacemanScott mentioned, you can use a 5 V, zener diode with series resistor to limit the current, or other methods depending on the other modules you have in your schematics.
One thing is clear, not to use the same component generated 5V for reset line.